# When to use memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I`m planing to use memcached in one of my websites. 
Here is from memcached home page

> Memcached is an in-memory key-value
>   store for **small** chunks of arbitrary
>   data

I consider to use memcached in search/result page where every query returns about 4kb (text).

In this case is it reasonable to use memcached ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

I current use Memcache on a number of sites and regulary stores blobs of 50kb and more.  Personally I would say that anything below 500kb would be fine, however I would recommend that you have a look through the memcache docs for specifics.

**EDIT**

Just checked one of my busier servers, the largest blob I have in memcache is 77.2kb and all is running fine.

Comment: How many megabytes should I assign when I am launching the deamon ?
I have 1gb available for this task.
And how long should I keep stored data ?
You mean everyone of store blobs is around 50kb, right ?

Comment: That largely depends on how many chunks of data you plan to store in Memcache, so a little fine tuning will be necessary.  I would suggest that you start high and then review the usage and tune from there.  If you haven't got it already Memcache has an admin PHP script that you can run to view the current status of the services and the data that is currently stored.  Using this will allow you to better tune the service for your particular setup and usage.

Comment: Thanks. I`m allocated 512mb of ram for memcached.
Will see if is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's a reasonable use for memcached. The limit is [1 megabyte](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_data_size_you_can_store?_%281_megabyte%29), so your 4KB cache size should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, that should be fine. Typically anything up to 1MB is fine.